# Javascript window.open() but in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Im developing a website where, in a given moment, i need to redirect the user to an url passing a `'_system'` parameter. I know this in javaScript is something like `window.open('xxx.com', '_system')`, but i wanna know if there is way to do this using Laravel and its `redirect()` response helper and how to do that.

Comment: PHP is a server side technology, so no you cannot perform client side functionality in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the external url into the `redirect()` method and it will redirect to that url.

For example: `return redirect('https://www.google.com');`

Comment: And what about the '_system' parameter?

Comment: There is no `_sytem` parameter. It's a name of browser window opened with js. With Laravel you are making HTTP redirect.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you just worded the question badly and were essentially asking how to redirect to an external url in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks for the explain about the _system window